# Find unknown string around my string

Tags: php

I just want to find unknown text around my string between two spaces.
For example:

```
$mystring = "blabalbla <b>sometext</b> <b>ssssss</b>"
```

What I want to do with this:

I know the "sometext" but I want to put in a string the

```
<b>sometext</b>.
```

But my string is always changing, forexample it can be:

```
<s><b>sometext</b></s>
```

Now I need to put the whole into a string

```
<s><b>sometext</b></s>.
```

So I can't use simply attaching my variable to

```
<b>.mystring.</b>
```

beacuse in cases I can have unknown strings around it.

How can I do this? Or is there another way to find and delete those

```
<b><s><i></b></s></i> etc....  around my string?
```

Thnaks, Creep.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
$mystring = preg_replace('/(^|\s)(?:<[^>]*>)*sometext(?:<[^>]*>)*(\s|$)/i', '$1'.$some_new_text.'$2', $mystring);
```

I tested this against what you provided, is should work pretty well.  It handles the text being on it's own, at the start or end of the string, and surrounded by an unlimited number of html entities.

**Description**

- Match either the start of the string, or a space `(^|\s)`
- Followed by zero or more html nodes `(?:<[^>]*>)*`

  - These are in a non-capturing group, so they don't get assigned a group number
- Followed by the known string

  - If you plan on having this string be dynamic, you will need to use the `preg_quote` method to escape any special characters
- Followed by zero or more html nodes `(?:<[^>]*>)*`
- Followed by either a space or the end of the string `(\s|$)`
- Match case-insensitvely `/i` (optional)

Notice that the leading and trailing spaces (if any) are added back in on the replacement string `$1` and `$2`.